# React How to pass arguments to function

Tags: reactjs

Hi I found a question asking the same thing but they coded completely different using 'class name extends', I am just using 'function name'. I was wondering how I would I solve this problem or do I have to rewrite my program.

I have styles at the bottom I left off.

Window.js

```
import React from 'react';
import "../css/Start.css";



export default function Window(nuts) {

    let ulList=[]
    for (let i=0;i<nuts.file.length;i++) {
      ulList.push(<li>
        {
            nuts.file[i]
        }
      </li>)
    }


    let imageList=[]
    for (let i=0;i<nuts.image.length;i++) {
        imageList.push(<img src={nuts.image[i]} alt={nuts.image[i]}/>)
    }


    return (
        <div style={main}>
            <p>{nuts.name}</p>
            <p>{nuts.date}</p>
            <p>{nuts.note}</p>
          {ulList}
          {imageList}
          <button> Demo </button>


        </div>
    );
  }
```

Project.js

```
import React from 'react';
import Background from '../images/projectbackground.jpg';
import "../css/Start.css";
import Window from './Window'



export default function Project() {

  const files = ['f1','f2','f3']
  const images = ['p1','p2','p3']
  const nuts = {name:'phil',date:'2/2/16',note:'this is a note',file:files,image:images}

  return (
      <div style={main}>
          <Window nuts={nuts}/>
          <div style={footer}>

          </div>
      </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your [function component](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html#function-and-class-components) will get passed *all* the properties together in an object.

There are three changes you could make to have this work:

- render `<Window {...{nuts}} />` instead (not recommended but is an option)
- change parameters to `function Window(props)` and all your other code to say `props.nuts` instead of just `nuts`
- change parameters to `function Window({nuts})` to [destructure](https://2ality.com/2015/01/es6-destructuring.html) the (no longer named) "props" object

Answer (score 0):

`nuts` is being passed to `Window` via the `props` object.

You either need to destructure `nuts` in-line or in your function body.

```
function Window({ nuts })
```

or

```
function Window(props) {
    const { nuts } = props;
}
```